# Can GradientColor be defined in another file for a vector drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector drawable that I am using in an Android app.  One of the path elements has a fillColor set to a gradient.  This is defined in the XML and it works great when the target device is running API 24 or later.  I can have it work for older versions by placing having two versions of the vector drawable.  One using a solid color fpr fillColor in the res/drawable folder and the one with the gradient in a res/drawable-v24 folder.  Is it possible to define the gradient in another file so that it could be referenced as a color in <24 and as a gradient in 24 (and later)?  Something like

```
<path
    android:pathData="some random path inserted here"
    android:fillColor="@color/myGradient">
```

Is there a way to define a gradient so that it can be referenced in that way?